# Update npm dependencies while keeping the Angular version

Tags: angular, npm, jestjs, npm-check-updates

I want to update my project's dependencies but keep the Angular version.

Since `npm update` only updates within the version range specified in package.json, I chose [npm-check-updates](https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates) (`ncu`) to more widely detect possible updates:

```
ncu --minimal --peer --reject @angular*
```

The output includes two types of suggested updates (exemplary):

```
glob    ^9.2.1  →  ^10.2.2
jest   ^28.1.3  →  ^29.5.0
```

✅ The `glob` line is what I am looking for: a dependency that can be updated.

❗ Updating `jest` (and others similar), on the other hand, causes conflicts

```
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: jest@28.1.3
npm WARN   peer jest@"^28.0.0" from jest-preset-angular@12.2.2
npm WARN     jest-preset-angular@"12.2.2" from @angular-builders/jest@14.1.0
```

indicating that `@angular-builders/jest` (in other cases also `@angular-devkit/build-angular` and `@angular/compiler-cli`) would also have to be updated to the next major version (Angular 15), which I wanted to avoid.

Why did `ncu --peer` fail to detect this (and accordingly *not* suggest the update of `jest`)?

How else can possible dependency updates be detected under the constraint of maintaining compatibility with the existing (or a particular) Angular version across transitive dependencies?

Comment: Jest is a special case. I wouldn’t upgrade to v29 unless on Angular 16 and I’d probably give it a few weeks for issues to close out.

Comment: The question isn't when or how to upgrade Jest, but how to more reliably determine which packages can be upgraded.

Comment: As a work-around, the *doctor mode* (`ncu -du`) helped in my case to only apply updates that wouldn't cause errors.

Comment: What is your npm and node version?

Comment: node v18.16.0, npm v9.6.7